# sqoop to teradata - column length issue

Tags: teradata, sqoop

I am trying to sqoop a table's data from HIVE to Teradata and got the error

`Error: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 1186] [SQLState HY000] Parameter 8 length is 67618 bytes, which is greater than the maximum 64000 bytes that can be set.`

Can anyone please suggest exactly what change I have to do here? Column-8 is too long string in HIVE table and that is why I have defined the data type in TERADATA as `VARCHAR(50000)`, but still it is failing.

```
Error: com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 1186] [SQLState HY000] Parameter 8 length is 67618 bytes, which is greater than the maximum 64000 bytes that can be set.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:94)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:74)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.internalSetString(TDPreparedStatement.java:1121)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.setString(TDPreparedStatement.java:1095)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.setObject(TDPreparedStatement.java:1631)
    at com.teradata.connector.teradata.TeradataObjectArrayWritable.write(TeradataObjectArrayWritable.java:232)
    at com.teradata.connector.teradata.TeradataBatchInsertOutputFormat$TeradataRecordWriter.write(TeradataBatchInsertOutputFormat.java:142)
    at com.teradata.connector.teradata.TeradataBatchInsertOutputFormat$TeradataRecordWriter.write(TeradataBatchInsertOutputFormat.java:114)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorOutputFormat$ConnectorFileRecordWriter.write(ConnectorOutputFormat.java:107)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorOutputFormat$ConnectorFileRecordWriter.write(ConnectorOutputFormat.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorMMapper.map(ConnectorMMapper.java:129)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorMMapper.run(ConnectorMMapper.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

    at com.teradata.connector.teradata.TeradataBatchInsertOutputFormat$TeradataRecordWriter.write(TeradataBatchInsertOutputFormat.java:151)
    at com.teradata.connector.teradata.TeradataBatchInsertOutputFormat$TeradataRecordWriter.write(TeradataBatchInsertOutputFormat.java:114)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorOutputFormat$ConnectorFileRecordWriter.write(ConnectorOutputFormat.java:107)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorOutputFormat$ConnectorFileRecordWriter.write(ConnectorOutputFormat.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:658)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorMMapper.map(ConnectorMMapper.java:129)
    at com.teradata.connector.common.ConnectorMMapper.run(ConnectorMMapper.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Comment: `67618 bytes` is definitely more than `VARCHAR(50000)`. Aditionally data from Hive is probably Unicode and then the max size is 32000.

Comment: So what can be possible data type for Teradata, which resolves the issue

Comment: The max length for a varchar column is 64000, and as @dnoeth points out, 67618 is greater than both 50000 and 64000.  Varchar isn't going to work. If you re-defined the target column as clob(70000), you can't still be receiving the error you've got in your post.

Answer (score 0):

String column in Hive has 67618 characters and you are mapping it with `VARCHAR(50000)` of Teradata.

**So the error is expected.**

You should use `Clob(70000)` for this.

Sqoop Export should work for this.

Comment: shared in the original post

Comment: @KoushikChandra as you are using `clob(70000)` so bytes are greater than 67618. So can't be the same I guess.